# Conditional Configuration in Apache based on HTTP Headers

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to do some conditional Configuration in Apache based on one particular HTTP request header.

For eg., 
Enable HTTP Digest Authentication for a set of Client IP Address and enable HTTP Basic Authentication for another set of Client IP Address.

For dynamically changing the configuration I am using .htaccess but i am not able to find a way to read the Client IP Address in the Configuration (.htaccess) and apply condition based on the IP Address. 
 I tried using mod header but i couldn't figure out the way. Please provide me some direction in this regards

Answer (score 0):

Would using the   tags fix your problem ?

https://blogs.apache.org/httpd/entry/new_in_httpd_2_4